# MLP in keras : overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using `keras` for a regression problem. The predicted value must be positive and can be greater than 1, hence I'm using ReLu as activation function for the output layer. While training, i get a strange `MSE` plot:
[MSE plot (the validation mse is less than the training mse)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWENd.jpg)

I couldn't understand the meaning, is it an over-fitting situation or an under-fitting situation, and how can I deal with it?

Comment: I'm not too sure what the problem is - the plot shows that your error decreases during the first training epoch, isn't that what you want?

Comment: i had never seen a plot like this, is it normal to have the training plot above the validation plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a ReLu function for your output layer. A unit that uses a ReLu function becomes dead as soon as the input gets less than zero. Therefore, it will not change afterward. If you're working on a regression problem, just use a simple linear function as your activation function.

Comment: But in this case, i can get negative values.

Comment: Do you think that i can use "softplus" instead?

Comment: Yes, you may get negative values. But a neural network will train itself to get as close as possible to the training output. So, it will find its own way towards the answer. A softplus function could also help the problem. if I were you, I would just give both of them a shot.

Comment: Actually i tested the linear function and i got negative values while testing, that's why i replaced it with relu.
i'm using 'softplus' and i'm waiting for results. Thanks.

Comment: I think your model was underfitting in that case, because a neural network will find its way. You may needed more data. But using a ReLu function for output is probably a bad idea.

Comment: if i cant get more data, can i add more neurones or layers? (sorry for this question i'm a newbie)

Comment: Here are some of the things I learned from Andrew NG about when our model has high bias (underfitting).
1. use a bigger network. basically, increase the number of neurons.
2. train longer
3. use another architecture. (more hidden layers and etc.)
also, try to solve high bias first, and then if you were facing overfitting, try to fix that. (by using more data and etc.)
and don't be sorry for asking. we all start at some point.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know that over-fitting is a low loss function on the training set, but a high loss function on the test set. Second, you need to know if MSE is a loss function you use or an evaluation indicator for your regression task. I think you may have drawn a curve for the evaluation indicator here. You should actually look at the curve for the loss function. Finally, with regard to the selection of activation functions, the upper floor is quite right. It would be nice to use a linear activation function.

Comment: Yes i'm using MSE as a loss function.

Comment: Yeah. In this case, an under-fitting has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at the predicted values for your validation set, as well as the distributions of your `y` labels there.

Chances are that you are predicting a constant value but this constant value actually yields a lower MSE because of a presence of a bias in your validation set.

Then again, those are hypothesis of how you might end up with such a plot.

Comment: Actually i had looked at them.
I'm not prediction a constant value, but the values are very close for each other (i'm predicting a very small values) it can be the problem? if yes, how cani deal with it?